How to configure firebase emulator for the storage using Angular 17?
I know that I can use the following code to configure it. However after starting the application it uses the deployed storage url.
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    provideRouter(appRoutes),
    provideHttpClient(withInterceptors(httpInterceptorProviders)),
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,
    NotificationModule,
    AngularFireStorageModule,
    AngularFireDatabaseModule,
    AngularFireModule.initializeApp(environment.firebase),
    provideFirebaseApp(() => initializeApp(environment.firebase)),
    provideFirestore(() => {
      let firestore: Firestore;
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        firestore = initializeFirestore(getApp(), {
          experimentalForceLongPolling: true,
        });
        connectFirestoreEmulator(firestore, 'localhost', 8080);
      } else {
        firestore = getFirestore();
      }
      return firestore;
    }),
    provideAuth(() => {
      const auth = getAuth();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectAuthEmulator(auth, 'http://localhost:9099', {
          disableWarnings: true,
        });
      }
      return auth;
    }),
    provideFunctions(() => {
      const functions = getFunctions();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectFunctionsEmulator(functions, 'localhost', 5001);
      }
      return functions;
    }),
    provideStorage(() => {
      const storage = getStorage();
      if (environment.useEmulators) {
        connectStorageEmulator(storage, 'localhost', 9199);
      }
      return storage;
    }),
  ],
})
export class CoreModule {}

Why the development mode is not pointing to the localhost storage?

Changing the environment settings
Using the provideStorage with the emulator connection


Please edit the question to show the code that uses Storage that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to copy what you have and run it for ourselves.  What you show right doesn't doesn't actually do anything with storage, so we need more information to see how you are getting a hold of the returned storage.
